# installing a 360 rotating wood panel from the ceiling

Tags: wood, hinges, hardware

I want to install something similar to this image - I need to know what the hardware used is to support the wood hanging from the ceiling and in place on the floor still allowing for 360 rotation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The 50's called, they want their decor back....sorry, I couldn't help myself.

Google:   **Adjustable Threaded Pole Leveling Foot**

Comment: Hehe I like retro style - thanks for the tip!